Transaction using Safe Protocolkit with different versions of nested safe accounts
SAFE_A_1_1: 0x12a3e25c0160e886a5b12d0bf2d1620a23246cec
SAFE_B_1_1: 0x85DE39050457591c482eFCD230d18F0920D6b293
EOA: 0xFb273f88B43dB3c8de91284A2a80E6208c323367

Using Protocol kit, we are trying to do a transaction from SAFE_A.
Safe_B is owner of Safe_A.
EOA is owner of SAFE_B.

The Problem here is the Safe version of SAFE_A and SAFE_B is different.

Safe_A - v1.3.0
Safe_B - v1.4.1

It is throwing the following error while executing the transaction.
Error: missing revert data

For now, both Safe{Wallet} UI and Safe CLI can update to v1.3.0, as further versions are not yet supported. Support for updating Safes to v1.4.1 is a work in progress, which can be followed here.
If you cannot wait and know what you are doing, you can also try using the migration contract. This contract is the one that will be used by the Safe CLI when v1.4.1 support is released. Complete guides will be added to Safe documentation then.
Hope it helps; Best, Louis

Hey Louis, Wanted to confirm that the transaction from 1.4.1 safe won't work with 1.3.0 safe as an owner? And we will need to migrate the accounts to 1.4.1 to make it work?


Have you tried doing the same operation with two safes that have the same version? 2. If this is indeed the problem, yes you will have to upgrade your safe to v1.4.1. Best, Louis



Yes Louis, same code works for two v1.3.0 safes. But fails for cross version transaction with v1.4.1.
Would appreciate if you could point me to a deployed migration contract by Safe.

Would it be possible to downgrade to v1.3.0 instead?

The migration contract I linked in my previous comment is not deployed yet as it is awaiting audit validation. Unfortunately as of today the only way to downgrade a safe would be to use the same migration contract.
